# Creating a single index in Azure Cognitive Search from ADLS Gen2 (blob files) and CosmosDB (custom metadata)

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I am using Azure Cognitive Search for indexing blobs *(pdf/xlsx/pptx/docx/videos/images)* in an Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2. I also have an application for business users, allowing them to search accross all documents using the created indexes.

Now I need to allow business users to create customizable tags for any of the retrieved documents (i.e.: an user wants to tag a document with a tag named **project_name** and set its value to **project-lotus**). These tags will be created from our app and will be stored on a Cosmos DB collection.

- Is there a simple way to add these tags as new fields in the same blob index I'm already using in my application?

Ideally I want to have an index that is built from 2 sources: blob files (ADLS Gen2) and custom metadata related to each file (Cosmos DB).

Comment: It should be possible to do so. Please see this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/tutorial-multiple-data-sources. HTH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Optimize indexing with push API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/tutorial-optimize-indexing-push-api) or as suggested index from [multiple Azure data sources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/tutorial-multiple-data-sources) using .NET  SDK would be useful here as they support indexing the data from the Azure cosmos DB and merge the data stored in Azure Blob Storage.

Answer (score 1):

[Field mappings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-indexer-field-mappings) can be used for that!

They are useful when we need to populate an index field with data from more than one data source - in my case, ADLS Gen2 (blob files) and Cosmos DB (files metadata).

For more information, check this tutorial: [index from multiple data sources using the .NET SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/tutorial-multiple-data-sources)